# How to extract a string from another string wihout changing a characters case

Tags: python, split, lowercase

There are two variables.

A variable **drive** was assigned a drive path (string). 
A variable **filepath** was assigned a complete path to a file (string).

```
drive = '/VOLUMES/TranSFER'
filepath = '/Volumes/transfer/Some Documents/The Doc.txt'
```

First I need to find if a string stored in a **drive** variable is in a string stored in **filepath** variable. 
If it is then I need to extract a string stored in **drive** variable from a string stored in a **filepath** variable without changing both variables characters case (no changing to lower or uppercase. The character case should stay the same).

So a final result should be:

**`result = '/Some Documents/The Doc.txt'`**

I could get it done with:

```
if drive.lower() in filepath.lower(): result = filepath.lower().split( drive.lower()  )
```

But approach like this messes up the letter case (everything is now lowercase)
Please advise, thanks in advance!

## EDITED LATER:

I coould be using my own approach. It appear IF portion of the statement

```
if drive.lower() in filepath.lower():
```

is case-sensitive. And **drive in filepath** will return False if case doesn't match.
So it would make sense to lower()-case everything while comparing. But a .split() method splits beautiful regardless of the letter-cases:

```
if drive.lower() in filepath.lower(): result = filepath.split( drive  )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if filepath.lower().startswith(drive.lower() + '/'):
    result = filepath[len(drive)+1:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`str.find`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

```
>>> drive = '/VOLUMES/TranSFER'
>>> filepath = '/Volumes/transfer/Some Documents/The Doc.txt'
>>> i = filepath.lower().find(drive.lower())
>>> if i >= 0:
...     result = filepath[:i] + filepath[i+len(drive):]
...
>>> result
'/Some Documents/The Doc.txt'
```

Comment: `drive, filepath = '/gotcha', '/this/gotcha/bad'`